# Can I retrieve the HTML element in a django form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a ModelForm, MyForm. Help me write a method that returns html elements for each field present in the form.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    priority = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','data-role':'select'}),
        choices=((1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)),
        required=True,
        initial='3',
        label=_('Priority'),
        help_text=_("Please select a priority carefully. If unsure, leave it as '3'."),
    )

    due_date = forms.DateTimeField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','data-role':'datepicker'}),
        required=False,
    )

    def getFormHtml(self):
        #need to return a dictionary with the key being the form field name and value being the HTML tag for the respective element
```

Comment: Have you read the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#outputting-forms-as-html)? This is standard functionality of a Django `Form`.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_form = MyForm()
```

django has a built-in way to render a form you can also get the default rendering of a form in a view like this:

```
my_form.as_p()
```

or

```
myform_as_table()
```

so you could extend your MyForm object to have a method that returns the form as html from a given form instance:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    priority = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','data-role':'select'}),
        choices=((1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)),
        required=True,
        initial='3',
        label=_('Priority'),
        help_text=_("Please select a priority carefully. If unsure, leave it as '3'."),
    )

    due_date = forms.DateTimeField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','data-role':'datepicker'}),
        required=False,
    )
    def getFormHtml(self):
        return self.as_table()
```

of course this would only make sense if you need the html of a form in a different view. If you need the html of a form in a template you can get the form in the template by adding `{{my_form.as_table}}` into the template or [render the form fields manually in the template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)

Comment: Thanks! I'm expecting a dictionary with the key being the form field name and value being the HTML tag for the respective element. Is it possible?

Comment: do you need those values in a view or a template?

Answer (score 0):

Upon submit, you get the field values using the 'name' attribute of the element. You could get the form method(post/get) but the html tag won't make it to the view.